# Count values in Dictionary using LINQ and LINQ extensions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>>

test1 : 1,3,4,5
test2 : 2,3,6,7
test3 : 2,8
```

How can I get a count of all the values using LINQ and LINQ extensions?

Comment: Please explain what exactly do you want to count?

Comment: I want to count all the values. I know how to count the keys by simply doing a .Count on the Dictionary. So in the case above the count should come back with 10.

Comment: Why the down vote? I explained that I wanted to get the count of all the Values... Dictionaries have Keys and Values... how is this not clear? I tried googling it and searching on stack overflow but did not find an example which fit my requirements. I also believe if I wanted to know how to do this, other people will too and someone will find this question useful in the future.

Comment: @Vitaliy No Worries, Just asking for whoever did to explain why. Read the reasons why people should down vote and don't believe my 'Question' fits into any of these.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> dict = ...
```

If you want the number of lists, it's as simple as:

```
int result = dict.Count;
```

If you want the total count of all the strings in all the lists:

```
int result = dict.Values.Sum(list => list.Count);
```

If you want the count of all the distinct strings in all the lists:

```
int result = dict.Values
                 .SelectMany(list => list)
                 .Distinct()
                 .Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah it was the total count of all the strings in all the lists I was after. Very concise and well explained answer. I am new to Linq so am still getting use to how to do things.

Comment: I was also after the way to do it using from mylist in dict where logic too, which would be useful to see how to do the same. thanks

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
yourdictionary.Values.Sum(l => l.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to count each item separately:

```
dict.Values.SelectMany(s => s).GroupBy(s => s)
    .Select(g => new {Value = g.First(), Count = g.Count});
```

With your sample you'll get:

"1", 1; "3", 2; "4", 1; "5", 1, "6", 1; "7", 1; "8", 1